# Graphql, how to return empty array instead of null

Tags: graphql

I'm new in Graphql and i'd like to know if there is a way to return an empty array instead of null in a relation.
Let pick the classic example with User and Post

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  posts: [Post]
}

Type Post {
  id: ID!
  comment: String!
}
```

when i make a query on an user without any post i'd like to have an empty array on posts attribute, but now i get `null`, how can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what server implementation language?

Answer (score 6):

This needs to be done in your GraphQL schema (rather than your GraphQL query) - your GraphQL field resolver should return an array instead of null and (optionally) specify that the array it returns is non-null; for example:

```js
const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: ID!
    posts: [Post!]!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  User: {
    posts(user, _args, { getPosts }) {
      return (await getPosts({user_id: user.id})) || [];
    }
  }
}
```