# GraphQL - Default values instead null

Tags: graphql, nosql

How to set global behavior of GraphQL with default values for `object` and `array` ?

**Some examples**

```js
const AddressTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
    name: 'Address',
    fields: {
        street: {type: 'String',defaultValue: null},
        number: {type: 'String', defaultValue: null},
        postcode: {type: 'String', defaultValue: null},
        city: {type: 'String', defaultValue: null},
        comment: {type: 'String', defaultValue: null},
        country: {type: 'String', defaultValue: null},
        quality: {type: 'QualityEnum', defaultValue: 'BAD'},
    }
});

const customerTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
    name: 'Customer',
    fields: {
        address: AddressTC
        needs: {
            type : ['objectID'],
            defaultValue: []
        },
        documents: {
            type: schemaComposer.getOTC('Document').List,
            defaultValue: []
        },
    }
});
```

In my case I use noSQL database and when a field doesn't exist or is empty, the request GraphQL always returns `null` then crashed my app with wrongs data type.

INFO : *I use graphql-compose*

---

I found this post, whith the same problem, but this solution not useful for me with a large API and dynamics resolvers. [Graphql, how to return empty array instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766939/graphql-how-to-return-empty-array-instead-of-null)

Comment: nullable type here ... value passed from DB is not undefined (?) then no default used? ... it's resolver role to return/provide matching/proper/required data